# Pass object from view to controller or controller to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have question about spring mvc.

Is it possible to pass a object from view to controller or controller to controller?

I have class called person(its consists of persons name, age, address).

I tried something like this, but this doesnt work.

first off I passed the object from my controller to the view like this

```
model.addAttribute("person",person);
return "table";
```

In the table.jsp file I made a link

```
< a href="validate.html?person=${person}" >validate< /a >
```

And on the validation controller I did something like this

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/validate",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String validate(@RequestParam("person")Person person, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("message",person.getName);
            return "validate";
}
```

Is it possible? If it is, then how?

Comment: think about it like this - how could a Person object be passed in a URL? A URL is only a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in this way. If you are using Spring 3.1.x, you just have to do:
< a href="validate.html?name=${person.name}&age=${person.age}..." >validate< /a >

and then in your controller, you have:

```
public String validate(Person person) {
   return "validate";
}
```

A better way will be to populate the Session instead of the Model. The Session contains serializable object :)

Here for more informations about news Spring MVC features: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do it in the way you want using the [Converter SPI](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Converter-API).  You implement the Converter interface, which from the spring documentation in the link looks like this:

```
package org.springframework.core.convert.converter;

public interface Converter<S, T> {
    T convert(S source);
}
```

from String to Person, and another from Person to String.  So your implementation would be something like this

```
public class PersonToStringConverter<Person, String> {
    String convert( Person person ) {
        // some code here that serializes your Person object 
        // into a String that you can later parse back into a person.
        return mySerializedPerson;
    }
}
```

and then an implement of StringToPersonConverter that does the parsing and populates and returns a Person object.  Then follow the directions in the Spring documentation to configure your converter for use and you are ready to go.

Given your usage above, you would need to url encode the serialized person for use in the href of your 'a' tag.